# Why my ActionButton won't appear in my ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

res/menu/mainmenu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:logo="@drawable/logout"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"/>


</menu>
```

MainMenu.java
    public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

```
    Button userinfo, requestservice, makepayment, trackparcel, checkcard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        // setupActionBar();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        userinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
        requestservice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestservice);
        makepayment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makepayment);
        trackparcel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.usertrackbutton);
        checkcard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkcard);

        userinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, UserInfo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        requestservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, RequestService.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        makepayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Payment.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        trackparcel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, TrackParcel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        checkcard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, CheckCard.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this)
                .setTitle("Logout")
                .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,
                                        Login.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainMenu.this);
                                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                                edit.clear();
                                edit.commit();
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // user doesn't want to logout
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_logout: {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this)
                    .setTitle("Logout")
                    .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,
                                            Login.class);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainMenu.this);
                                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                                    edit.clear();
                                    edit.commit();
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // user doesn't want to logout
                                }
                            }).show();
        }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

What I want to ask is that why my action items won't appear in my ActionBar eventhough I already wrote `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` **or** `android:showAsAction="always"` I don't know why it behave like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending `ActionbarActivity` suggests you use Actionbar from the support library.

Change to

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:logo="@drawable/logout"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"/>


</menu>
```

Quoting docs

> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace
>   defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML
>   attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do
>   not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use
>   your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the
>   support library.

Comment: Wow it's great. But I want the icon to be appear in actionBar instead of the text only

Comment: @Jiazzyuser another quote from the docs If your menu item supplies both a title and an icon—with the title and icon attributes—then the action item shows only the icon by default. If you want to display the text title, add "withText" to the showAsAction attribute. For example: `<item appshowAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>`

Comment: also note that if there is not enough space it appears in the overflow menu

Comment: another note  The "withText" value is a hint to the action bar that the text title should appear. The action bar will show the title when possible, but might not if an icon is available and the action bar is constrained for space. Could read the whole thing @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: yeah the problem solved. Once I change it from `android:logo` to `android:icon` the action items display the icon instead of text

Comment: @Jiazzyuser your original problem is solved by `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` not what you just suggested

Answer (score 0):

I have done the silly mistake here..
This is the correct code of what I have changed

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_logout"/>

</menu>
```

Change `android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_settings"` to `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"`